# Database Design Flaw

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Im having a hard time wrapping my head around a design flaw and I'm really hoping the community can help me out. My current design is:

```
SUBMISSIONS table

submission_ID (pk, int)
company_id (fk, int)
product_id (fk, int)
vendor_id (fk, int)
category (VARCHAR)
price (INT)
approval_status (TINYINT)
notes (MEDIUMTEXT)

VENDOR table

vendor_ID (pk, int)
vendor_name (VARCHAR)    

COMPANY table

company_id (pk, int)
company_name (VARCHAR)

PRODUCTS table

product_id (pk, int)
product_name(VARCHAR)
```

My Project is vendors submitting products to companies for review. The companies have a dashboard that contains a grid that pulls up all products submitted by vendors to them, they review them, then either approve or deny the products for use.

My issue is this...When pulling up the pending products grid I am grouping the submissions by their category. This way if there are 100 products in a category(which is common), they only have to see the category, not the individual products. They can enter notes on the group of submissions in a modal window that pops up from the grid. The id of the window is the first submission in the group and that submission is where the notes are stored. My major concern is that they can approve or deny submissions from the group individually so what happens when they enter notes for the group which is attached to the first submission in the group and then they deny that first submission. Now when they log in again all the notes for the group will seem to be gone because the notes are attached to that first submission which now sits in their denied products folder. There must be a better way of tracking notes to the group originally and then making those notes available to the individual submissions later but I'm not seeing it with my limited database design skills.  Any advice at this point is helpful.

Comment: Can you have more than one product in a submission?

Comment: Also, if notes are entered in the modal, does that indicate that all rows displayed are denied?

Comment: Each submission is just one product with its own price. Notes are entered in the modal to simply keep track of if the company wants to approve the product or not. In MOST cases all submissions in a group will be approved or denied together. That category essentially approved or denied all together. But sometimes one submission will be denied and the other 99 in that group will be approved. In my current design if the one submission/product denied is the first one submitted I'm screwed because those notes will be lost both while the submission group is being evaluated and later for reference.

Comment: "In MOST cases all submissions in a group will be approved or denied together." When you have more experience, you won't say that. You'll say "Not all submissions in a group will be approved or denied together."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is

- CREATE TABLE categories (id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(250) not NULL, UNIQUE INDEX(name), notes MEDIUMEXT)
- replace `category (VARCHAR)` with `category (fk, int)` in `SUBMISSIONS`
- drop `notes (MEDIUMTEXT)` in `SUBMISSIONS`
- Now attach notes to category table

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback. I think that is getting close to what I need. I'm just a little confused on how I tie that back to the submissions table. So do you propose when a vendor submits a product and creates a row in submissions table I also create a row in categories table. Then all subsequent submissions do a check of the categories table and if an entry exists make a FK entry in submissions for the category? I'm running some scenarios through my mind so it would helpful if I knew this is where you were going with this design. Thanks so much again...

Comment: The submission isn't just for a category, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed obviously you would need to create a category for single submissions.

Comment: @DevNewb This is exactly what I meant: If you think about it, the notes **allways** go to a category - but it can happen, that a category only has one entry.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. This is exactly what I was looking for. It answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should create a table for Categories, and a Submission would store a CategoryID.

You are executing a query to retrieve all of the items displayed in your modal.  When you update Submissions in the group, you must also update all of the records.

So basically your update statement would be:

```
UPDATE Submissions
SET notes = @notes, approval_status = @approval_status
WHERE (same criteria from your select statement)
```

Since you are already narrowing down what you display in the modal, I assume you know how to send values to parameters to a SQL statement.

Comment: Your modal adds user-friendliness, but don't forget, that a category would have many products.  So, a note entered would be attached to the submission of the category/product combination, not to the category.  


For example, you have a category of Food.  So you have many items already approved in that category.  Your user uses your application, to approve/deny unapproved Food products.  For some reason, they are being denied; the denial doesn't attach to the entire category - you already have approved food there.  The denial belongs to each submission of a product in the Food category.

Comment: +1 for all the insight and help. Thanks again. So I think what you are saying is with this new schema all submissions will be tied to a product/category combination so if a product in that combination is denied it will still share the same notes with products that have been approved correct? If that is what you are saying I am okay with that. As long as the company can look through their approved products and see notes as to why they approved that product then it will work. Is your concern that they cannot attach a specific note to a denied product?

Comment: Just re-read your comment and I think I see what you are saying. I actually have another table already that has 4000 product categories so with the new schema proposed here I am going to have a submission/notes table that will have a foreign key to the categories table. It sounds like your concern is that notes will be attached to an entire category but I wont set it up that way. Notes will be attached to a submission/category combo.

Comment: Well, not exactly.  When you update the SUBMISSIONS table, you need to update based on the criteria used to SELECT the items for the modal.  Only those submissions would share the same note.  I suggest that you SELECT categories for the modal that have submissions whose approval_status = not approved.  Then, when you UPDATE your data, you only UPDATE Submissions whose approval_status = not approved (or whatever status is appropriate) and where the CategoryID's = categories with Submissions not approved.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my concern.  There is no need to put a note on a record that doesn't pertain to what was selected in the modal.